# Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: php, macos, openssl, apple-push-notifications

i tried to run using local mac machine but go the following errors

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Unable to set private key file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns-dev.pem’ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns.php on line 9

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: failed to create an SSL handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns.php on line 9

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns.php on line 9

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns.php on line 9

Warning: socket_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns.php on line 11

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apns/apns.php on line 12
```

I got PEM certificated generated from other machine,

So I am totally confused what I have to do now.

Please let me know what I need to do to run it in localhost

Comment: i am having the same proble , i am able to run in my local XAMPP Server.

But it is not running in my external server.

Comment: Hi Biranchi, Just check with your Hosting provider for whitelisting the ports

That will solve your issue

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think that you may have exported the certificate, but not the private key from the .cer file that apple supplies.

These instructions from markbates might help out:

> Once you have the certificate from
>   Apple for your application, export
>   your key and the apple certificate as
>   p12 files. Here is a quick walkthrough
>   on how to do this:
>
> 1. Click the disclosure arrow next to your certificate in Keychain Access
>      and select the certificate and the
>      key.
> 2. Right click and choose `Export 2 items…`.
> 3. Choose the p12 format from the drop down and name it `cert.p12`.
>
> Now covert the p12 file to a pem file:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out apple_push_notification_production.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

Comment: hi jessecurry

Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Its working great, except one warning

Warning: socket_close(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource.

Could you please tell me what might be the problem ?

Comment: That sounds like a php error. What version of php are you using? And what are you passing to socket_close()?

Comment: iam using pHP version 5

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

socket_close($apns);

Comment: I'm not really a PHP guy, but I think that you might use fclose() when you create with stream_socket_client. I *think* that socket_close() works with socket_create(), don't take it too seriously though, I may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I was using a slightly different method of converting the certificate and key separately and although in the past it had worked it no longer did when I needed to renew. This method worked perfectly and was easier.

Comment: @KamalChalla  I have the same issue about the stream_socket_client(): SSL: Connection reset by peer , stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto Did you solve that ?