# Trouble connecting to APNs with PHP script

Tags: php, iphone, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am having some trouble with my push notifications. I have read through heaps of tutorials and have come up with the script below. I can't seem to get a connection to the APNs. Just to clarify, I am not coding the app side code for the app. I only know PHP and other web based languages.

I have gone throughout the process of creating the .pem file form my  certificate and private key. I also have a SSL certificate for my web server (I did this through my web host provider, not sure if that is the right way about doing this). I am just not sure exactly what has to happen in order to test that everything is working fine.

When I load the script on the web page i get the error: Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out

Can you please look through the code and help me find the reason that I am not able to connect to APNs. Also is there a way i can get a more details error report?

Here is my code: (The problem should be in the first 15 or so lines.)

```
<?PHP
$username = $_GET['username'];
$userIDarr = $_GET['userARR'];
$message = $username.' is d2P';
$passphrase = 'mypass'; // not sure what this refers too.. (from what i have read I think it is meant to be for the iphone side of things)

$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'ck.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 10, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if (!$apns)
    exit("Failed to connect: $error $errorString" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to Apple service. ' . PHP_EOL;

@mysql_connect ("localhost","down2par_down2pa","4m329aMh") or die ("could not connect to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db ("down2par_d2pdb") or die ("no database");

// create array of all device IDs AND badges that will be receiving notifications
$SQLarr = implode(" AND userid =", $userIDarr);
$DB = mysql_query("SELECT diviceID, badge FROM new_fb_users WHERE userid = '$SQLarr'");



while($DBarr = mysql_fetch_array($DB)) {

    $deviceToken = $DBarr['deviceID'];
    $badge = $DBarr['badge'];
    $id = $DBarr['id'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE new_fb_users SET badge = badge+1 WHERE id = $id");

    // create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => ($badge > 0 ? $badge + 1 : 1)
        );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0).pack('n', 32).pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)).pack('n', strlen($payload)).$payload;
    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($apns, $msg, strlen($msg));
    if (!$result)
        echo 'Failed message'.PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Successful message'.PHP_EOL;
}

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($apns);
?>
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Check this link. It helped me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481443/apple-push-notification-service

Comment: Hey Brad, thanks for the tip. I was planning on getting that done before I launched the update.

Answer (score 1):

Passphase is a secret key that you enter while creating p12 file.
Recal what you entered when you exported your p12 file.
For more details refer [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)

[image: refer this link]

Hope this help you

Comment: Hi, That is the tutorial I used to create my .pem file. 

I followed all steps and executed this test line :

Comment: (accidentally added above comment half way through)
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.232.226...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: And the Test was successful, But when i did the next test:
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey.pem: 
I was not successful. I think it might have something to do with my SSL.. It didn't mention anything in that tutorial about what to do with your SSL once you get it. Am I supposed to include that somewhere?

Comment: have u changed your passphase ?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. Is there a way to check?

Comment: You need to change this line `$passphrase = 'mypass'; // not sure what this refers too.. (from what i have read I think it is meant to be for the iphone side of things)`. This you cant get from any where AFAIK. If you have created p12 file then recall what you entered else contact person who created that file

Comment: Ok so I need to add my password that I set as the passphrase variable? But the other thing is, that variable is not being used anywhere. Where should I include it in the code?

Comment: Oops you need this line as well `stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);`