# warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to set private key file

Tags: php, ios, ssl

unable to get this getting these errors when running PHP in terminal as php simplepush.php

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file `/users/accenture/Desktop/newAPNS/ck.pem' in /users/accenture/Desktop/newAPNS/simplepush.php on line 22

Warning: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle in /users/accenture/Desktop/newAPNS/simplepush.php on line 22

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /users/accenture/Desktop/newAPNS/simplepush.php on line 22

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /users/accenture/Desktop/newAPNS/simplepush.php on line 22

Failed to connect: 0
```

I created all certificates and pem file by using raywenderlich article,  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1#comments

Comment: Can you show us the chmod of: ```/users/accenture/Desktop/newAPNS/```?

Comment: accenture:newAPNS accenture:$ php simplepush.php

Comment: usage: chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...

Comment: now i successfully run the php and i'm getting notification, main problem is creating p12 file, i used to create p12 file using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481443/apple-push-notification-service. this is working

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Problem is pem file wasn't correct, I created pem file using http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 . 
Creation of p12 file and with p12 creating pem file are not working for me. Correct process to create p12 and with p12 creating pem file as bellow

Once you have the certificate from Apple for your application, export your key and the apple certificate as p12 files. Here is a quick walkthrough on how to do this:

1. Click the disclosure arrow next to your certificate in Keychain Access and select the certificate and the key.
2. Right click and choose Export 2 items….
3. Choose the p12 format from the drop down and name it cert.p12.

Now convert the p12 file to a pem file:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out apple_push_notification_production.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

This is working for me, now I am getting a push notification.

Comment: @norganik Thank you Soooo much . This was grate .. it works

Comment: This saved me so much time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

Converting the key file to pem recommend in http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 was causing problems for me.

Running

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keyname.p12 -out keyname.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

instead of the

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out keyname.pem -in keyname.p12
```

solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HGPnuiLHM0) tutorial which is nearly same as raywenderlich article. I've just forgot to add PEM pass phrase. After adding it, as described [here](https://github.com/sivaganeshsg/PHP-Push-Notification-File/blob/master/apns_php.php), it worked:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'MyPassPhrase');
```