# stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key on ios Push Notification in php

Tags: php, ios, ssl

I am sending push notification to my ios app using php as my backend. Here is my code:

```
  $deviceToken = "XXXX";
  $ctx = stream_context_create();
  // ck.pem is your certificate file
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/ck.pem');
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'xxxx');
  // Open a connection to the APNS server
  $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
  if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => array(
            'title' => "haia",
            'body' => "how are you",
         ),
        'sound' => 'default'
    );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
    if (!$result)
        return 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        return 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
```

In the above code i am getting this error

```
  Message: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file `/home/developer/workspace/codeigniter/Ekattor/uploads/ck.pem'
  Message: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle
  Message: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
  Message: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
```

But when i remove ssl form the stream_socket_client() function it doesn't show any error. If i included ssl in stream_socket_client() it shows the above error. I saw already solved answers but i didn't get any luck. Please someone help me to resolve this

Comment: check ck.pem file permission also make sure file exists

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890378/warning-stream-socket-client-unable-to-set-private-key-file

Comment: i recreated the pem file but still same error only. When remove ssl in the stream_socket_client() i didn't get the error. When i am using ssl only i am getting this error. Is it necessary to use ssl in stream_socket_client()?